# Removing redhat os from a dual boot linux operatin system

Tags: dual-boot

I have a system with 2 os - redhat os and ubuntu os. I want to remove redhat without removing ubuntu and use the harddisk space for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If GRUB is not installed on the same partition as RedHat, you can just **delete the partition that contains RedHat.**  Your Ubuntu install should have nothing on that volume and won't be affected.

You can do this using the "Disks" application.

You may need to run `sudo update-grub` to remove RedHat from the GRUB menu.

Comment: If the RHEL/Red Hat distro owns `grub` (and it's using grub to boot), this may result in a un-bootable system, ie. require `grub-install` to be run as well...  *Yes I'd fix that probably after it boot, but I'd at least warn/suggest it may need fixing instead of the panic when it no longer boots*.